# Impossible to unlink accounts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, linked-accounts

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25463/175011) answer states that it is possible to unlink accounts, but it seems to no longer be possible. I was advised to open a bug report, which is what I believe I am doing here. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That answer is outdated, since we unified the login and account system this is no longer possible.  You can now login to all sites with a single set of credentials which work everywhere, but as a result un-linking is no longer supported.

Once we phase out the last of the internal usage of GUIDs for "accounts" (the previous meaning), even the concept (read: PITA if you're a SE developer) of association will go away, as it's now automatic by design.

Comment: Wait, does that mean I will be automagically registered for all SE sites?

Comment: @NullUserException - You're already "registered" (you have credentials on your account), though that's a term with at least 10 meaning on meta...so no, not the "registered" you're thinking of.  We don't *automatically create users*, that process hasn't changed any.  We've talked about making the sign up process for existing accounts on a new site more streamlined, but making it automatic really isn't on the table, I think the vast majority would agree with us there.

Comment: @NickCraver I would really like to have an option to remove the "accounts" tab from public viewing. This way, I could change my nick on the various sites, which would mean that I have essentially unlinked. The reason for this is that I do not want people to be able to "piece together" various aspects of my inventions and thereby reduce the chance of getting them patented.

Comment: @NickCraver Another reason why I people might dislike this kind of association is for privacy reasons. There is a number of people who don't want to have their accounts publicly linked to one on [this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/human-sexual-response-and-non-platonic-relations), for example.

Comment: @NullUserException - Ok...but we won't be supporting this, it's *really* not feasible.

Comment: @NickCraver Not supporting this will lead to people creating multiple accounts. I do not see how this could be such a difficult feature to develop.

Comment: @I_like_traffic_lights - That's the intended behavior, if you want separate accounts, you need to maintain separate accounts.  However, if they're used for *malicious* purposes (sock puppet voting for example), we will merge them in that case.

Comment: @NickCraver Ok. Fair enough. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: To make it harder to see that two accounts belong to the same person, you need to also you different email addresses, since SE websites published the md5 hash of every email address.

Comment: @NickCraver So I registered for a separate account on a different site to ask a question I don't want linked to my main account for privacy reasons, but these accounts got merged. As the question already has an answer I can't delete it (and I might like it to stick around to get more answers). Any options? Anonymize question? Delete part of account on that site only?

Comment: @Dukeling, I agree with you. I have the same problem. New rules seem to be dictated by NSA.

Comment: @OssIgeno I flagged the applicable post (there was only one) and asked for it or my account on that site to be anonymized (which was done). I guess the automatic merging is for (potential?) spammers or (likely new) users that create multiple accounts accidentally - I understand this, but, as a (respectable?) highish reputation user, being treated like I fall into one of those categories isn't exactly nice.