# How to unlink a Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Impossible to unlink accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116475/impossible-to-unlink-accounts)

I have various accounts on different sites associated with each other. Now I would really like to unlink my travel Stack Exchange account with my main account, while keeping both. How is this possible?

Comment: Someone asked this a few days ago and the answer is that you can no longer unlink accounts. Looking for that post....