# What are the possible alternatives to maintain separate accounts for the 'Workplace' and 'Personal Productivity' sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I would like to unlink my *[Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/about)* and *[Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/about)* accounts from other Stack Exchange accounts. These accounts have some information to the incidents in my workplace and personal life which I would like to keep confidential to the group who knows my Stack Exchange ID and user name.

Many potential employers are also asking about my account name in Stack Exchange to assess my knowledge levels. I am happy to share my Stack Exchange, [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/about) and [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) accounts. At the same time I would like to keep my *Workplace* and *Personnal Productivity* accounts confidential as I see potential risk if they know incidents about my *WorkPlace* and *Personal Productivity*. Hence I would like to unlink these two accounts from other accounts. However, I learned from the post [Impossible to unlink accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116475/impossible-to-unlink-accounts) that unlink is not possible.

Since unlinking is not possible, what are the possible alternatives to maintain separate accounts for *Workplace* and *Personal Productivity*?

Edits Based on answers:
As per the answer of Knights who say Ni, I have tried to add more logins. How ever if I add login or remove login, this change is reflecting in all accounts. Hence as a result all of my accounts are linked to single login and single account.

Comment: Careful: "Personnel" refers to people in someone's employment, e.g. "military personnel".

Comment: `WordPress Answers and Personnal Productivity accounts confidential` Err.. WordPress Answers?

Comment: @nhahtdh that was a prob with [revision 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/179007/revisions)

Comment: Create a separate account with a separate login and *a separate email*

Comment: What happened to *Personal Productivity*? (It now says *"Couldn't find site"*. E.g., was it merged into another site?) Closing was [noted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331829/when-are-closed-sites-removed-from-sede).

Answer (score 6):

Edit: There's probably a better way to do this. Any other canonical answers? I can't find any.

Mods: Do you have the tools to handle this properly if it were flagged?

---

You actually *can* de-link them, though it's a bit of a pain and involves making a new email. It's a little hard to provide visual instructions from a phone, but I shall try:

1. Add a new email to your Workplace and Productivity accounts
2. Set those emails as the default account for both of those sites
3. Remove your old email from those two accounts

Voila. Two logins, two emails. Note that it might take a day or so for reputation and flair to update on the main StackExchange website.

Comment: How to add additional email ID to the existing account. I am seeing there is option to edit the existing email ID. However there is no option to add additional Email ID to the account please help.

Comment: @BVR Unfortunately I'm on a tablet, which makes it rather difficult to be of much assistance here. I will help tomorrow, though.

Comment: [Shog9's answer *How can I change my login email address for Stack Overflow?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114703/how-can-i-change-my-login-email-address-for-stack-overflow/114704#114704) to the rescue!

Comment: @PeterMortensen: If I change login for one account it is changing for all the accounts. I would like to change only for Workplace and Personnel productivity sites only

Answer (score 2):

As I understand per Creative Commons license it is required you be able to disassociate yourself from your content.  [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said) covers this; I started a bounty on it requesting SE staff make clear an official protocol for such a request.

Comment: While I support that request, I don't think that's what OP is looking for here. E wants to keep control of the posts e's made on Workplace and PP, but to make those other accounts undiscoverable from, e.g., eir SO account.