# When are closed sites removed from SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, closed-sites

Augur Stack Exchange has been closed down four days ago, according to its [Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur). Yet, it's [still visible in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/augur/query/1085679). I was wondering how long it would be kept; sites which have been closed for longer (e.g. Startups and Personal Productivity) are not available anymore.

<sub>Incidentally, while doing some research for this question I'd expected Arabic Stack Exchange to appear in [the list of databases](https://data.stackexchange.com/augur/query/1085680/database-names) since many of my cross-site queries make an exception for this site. Apparently, that is no longer necessary ...</sub>

Comment: I’ll take a look tomorrow and see what needs to be updated.

Comment: Afaik I made a mistake by not watching augur more :-( . The concept - open source prediction market - is so wonderful that we simply coldn't understand it.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if the system predicted the closure of its own SE site accurately ...

Comment: @Rob the page 404s because the *site* does not exist - it's part of the URL. I'm not sure if queries are deleted if their owner is - I don't expect so, just like with Q&A posts. I'm not sure if editing this very question will improve it - it could as well be considered [tag:status-completed].

Comment: I have noticed that [windowsphone.se] is still in SEDE - according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/windowsphone/query/1792908/most-recent-post), there were no posts since 2022. I am not really sure whether this should really be considered issue. Should I raise a separate question about this? (Perhaps viewed as a feature-request or a bug-report.)

Comment: @Martin yeah, by this time it's a bug. [JMG's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383954/295232) didn't receive an official response either.

Comment: I have posted a separated question here: [Should Windows Phone site be removed from SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394135)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While we automatically add new sites to public SEDE, the weekly refresh process doesn't remove closed sites. That means they are removed when we remember to do it.

I went ahead and manually removed the site from public SEDE and it shouldn't be included any longer when we refresh the SEDE each week. I've also created a To Do item for myself, to update the process to automatically drop databases and sites from the weekly refresh when they are permanently closed.

Comment: So all the closed sites that have been removed from it, have all been removed manually?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog Yes, that's correct

Comment: Because why would programmers program?

Comment: @Luuklag Come on man, I really doubt there are enough closed sites that pop up every week to warrant automation...