# How to isolate my programming related accounts from my other accounts?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, multiple-accounts

I have several accounts on StackExchange, but I would like keep my programming and IT accounts separated from the others.

Is there a way to create two personas ?

Comment: Sure. Two OpenID providers, just make sure to never cross vote or anything like that.

Comment: Also keep in mind that [it's not possible to unlink accounts anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116475/impossible-to-unlink-accounts).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Can you elaborate a little on this ? My accounts already exist.

Comment: Right now all your accounts are using the same OpenID provider e.g. Google. You will have to browse from a different browser or use Private/Incognito mode (since SE stores credentials in local storage) click login and create yourself whole new account using a different provider with a different email address behind it.